# nginx not logging upstream requests

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have my nginx running in k8s, correctly communicating with upstream Wildfly instances,
but only requests to nginx static locations are logged

```
    http {
        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        sendfile        on;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        proxy_send_timeout 300;
        keepalive_timeout  65;

        #gzip  on;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 256;
        #server_names_hash_max_size 32;

        log_format upstream_log '"$time_local" client=$remote_addr '
               'method=$request_method request="$request" '
               'request_length=$request_length '
               'status=$status bytes_sent=$bytes_sent '
               'body_bytes_sent=$body_bytes_sent '
               'referer=$http_referer '
               'user_agent="$http_user_agent" '
               'upstream_addr=$upstream_addr '
               'upstream_status=$upstream_status '
               'request_time=$request_time '
               'upstream_response_time=$upstream_response_time '
               'upstream_connect_time=$upstream_connect_time '
               'upstream_header_time=$upstream_header_time';

        server {
            listen       8080;
            server_name  localhost;
            root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

            include mime.types;
            types
            {
            application/javascript mjs;
            }

            gzip on;
            gzip_vary on;
            gzip_min_length 1024;
            gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
            gzip_types text/css text/javascript text/html text/xml image/svg+xml image/png application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml;
            gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

            location / {
              try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            }
            
            location ~ \.(html|json)$ {
              add_header Set-Cookie "Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure";
              add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always; # enable HSTS
              add_header Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
              add_header Expires "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT";
              add_header Pragma no-cache;
              # add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
              add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
              add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
              add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
              #add_header Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' ajax.googleapis.com www.google.com";
            }

            location ^~/rest {
              proxy_pass http://wildfly-be.wildfly-be.svc.cluster.local:8080/wildfly/rest;
            }

            error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
                root   html;
            }
    
            access_log /dev/fd/1 upstream_log;

        }

    }
```

of course, logged requests to static locations does not have proper upstream timings but a - dash instead

```
12/Feb/2024:16:13:25 +0100" client=192.168.4.39 method=GET request="GET /language/locale-en_GB.json HTTP/1.1" request_length=132 status=200 bytes_sent=433800 body_bytes_sent=433202 referer=- user_agent="kube-probe/1.23+" upstream_addr=- upstream_status=- request_time=0.000 upstream_response_time=- upstream_connect_time=- upstream_header_time=-
```

this seems to indicate that the variables from the upstream nginx module are somewhat defined.

I have followed official nginx documentation and other documentation as in https://onecompiler.com/questions/3src8rjkd/how-to-log-application-response-time-with-nginx
do you have any ideas why I have no upstream requests being logged?

I tried introducing a custom upstream_log format with proper variables

```
               'upstream_response_time=$upstream_response_time '
               'upstream_connect_time=$upstream_connect_time '
               'upstream_header_time=$upstream_header_time';
```

I am expecting to have requests to the `location ^~/rest` upstream logged too with proper timings while browsing the nginx frontend